# How to draw two triangles on a non-horizontal line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

I'm a beginner on TikZ package and trying to draw two triangles on a non-horizontal line, as shown below.

[image]

Is there any way to draw the triangles first on a straight line and then rotate them?

Comment: Welcome to TexSE.  The simple answer is "yes, as explained in the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)".  A quick search of the manual with the string "rotate" would show you that `\draw[rotate=30]...` might give you a starting point.  In general you will get more help here (a) if you ask a specific question about how to do something and (b) you show us what you have already tried in the form of a working example we can compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A starting point. The code duplication for the two triangles is avoided by a `\foreach` loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}    
  \def\AngleS{20}
  \def\AngleTheta{45}
  \def\RadiusTheta{.8cm}
  \def\ArrowLen{2cm}
  \definecolor{rosa}{HTML}{F79796}
  \definecolor{myred}{HTML}{EE1450}
  \definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{0083CA}
  \tikzset{
    myarrowtip/.tip={Triangle[length=12pt, width=8pt]},
    myarrow/.style={draw={#1},line width=2.5pt, -{myarrowtip}},
  }
  \draw
    (\AngleS:9cm) node (s) {$s$}
    (0, 0) --
    coordinate[pos=.22] (si)
    coordinate[pos=.66] (sf)
    (s)
  ;
  \foreach \start/\ssub in {si/i, sf/f} {
    \draw
      (\start) ++(\AngleS:\RadiusTheta)
      arc (\AngleS:\AngleS + \AngleTheta:\RadiusTheta)
      (\start) ++(\AngleS + \AngleTheta/2:\RadiusTheta + 1.5ex)
      node {$\theta$}
    ;
    \draw[myarrow=rosa]
      (\start) -- ++(\AngleS:\ArrowLen)
      coordinate (tmpA)
      node[below] {$\vec F_s$}
    ;
    \draw[myarrow=red]
      (\start) -- ++(\AngleS + \AngleTheta:{\ArrowLen/cos(\AngleTheta)})
      coordinate (tmpB)
      node[left] {$\vec F$}
    ;
    \draw[dashed] (tmpA) -- (tmpB);
    \fill[radius=3pt]
      (\start) circle[]
      ++(\AngleS - 90:1em) node {$s_{\ssub}$}
    ;
  }
  \draw[myarrow=myblue]
    (si) ++(\AngleS - 90:2em)
    -- node[below] {$\Delta \vec r$}
    ++(\AngleS:{(.66 - .22) * 9cm})
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Regarding the original question, whether it is possible to draw everything horizontally and then rotate it: Just replace all occurrences of `\AngleS` in the `\draw` commands by zero, and put the commands into a `scope` environment starting with `\begin{scope}[rotate=\AngleS]` and terminating with `\end{scope}`. This makes the code even a bit simpler (though it is already quite compact).

Comment: I suppose it also rotates the labels?

Comment: @Bernard No. It just rotates the coordinates. If you want to rotate anything, then the rotation needs to be applied to the canvas: `transform canvas={rotate=\AngleS}`.